# Show and Hide menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a tab menu in `CSS` and show the first menu by default. When you hover over the other menu items I need it to hide the one shown by default and show the menu of the selected one.

How can I hide the one shown by default on hover?

```css
  .sau-c-nav-side{
        nav{
            ul{
                li{
                    height: 50px;
                }
                li:hover .sau-c-nav-side__sub{
                    display: block;
                }
            }
            .sau-c-nav-side__sub{
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top:80px;
                bottom: 0;
                left:150px;
                &.active{
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
               <div class="sau-c-nav-side">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
                                <ul class="sau-c-nav-side__sub active">
                                    <li><a href="#">item1-menu1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">item2-menu1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">item3-menu1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
                                <ul class="sau-c-nav-side__sub">
                                    <li><a href="#">item1-menu2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">item2-menu2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">item3-menu2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
                                <ul class="sau-c-nav-side__sub">
                                    <li><a href="#">item1-menu3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">item2-menu3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">item3-menu3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to hide the first `li` when you are hovering over the entire `ul`. Then adjust your `li:hover` to a `ul:hover li:hover`

This will accomplish having the `li:first-child` continue to display when there is no hover.

Sorry, in my snippet I had to convert to plain CSS for the code to run.

Also, I reordered the rules for the cascade to work as you would like it to.

```css
.sau-c-nav-side nav ul li{
    height: 50px;
}
.sau-c-nav-side nav li:first-child .sau-c-nav-side__sub{
  display: block;
}
.sau-c-nav-side nav ul:hover li:first-child .sau-c-nav-side__sub{
display: none;
}
.sau-c-nav-side nav ul:hover li:hover .sau-c-nav-side__sub{
    display: block;
}

.sau-c-nav-side nav .sau-c-nav-side__sub{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:80px;
  bottom: 0;
  left:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sau-c-nav-side">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
                <ul class="sau-c-nav-side__sub active">
                    <li><a href="#">item1-menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2-menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3-menu1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
                <ul class="sau-c-nav-side__sub">
                    <li><a href="#">item1-menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2-menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3-menu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
                <ul class="sau-c-nav-side__sub">
                    <li><a href="#">item1-menu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2-menu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3-menu3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```